# Flutter App is not reflecting any new changes

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I was doing code in my flutter app, then suddenly new changes stopped reflecting in my app. I tried so many things but I noticed it lately that it's not reflecting the new changes.

I already tried the following ways to solve this problem.

1. hot reload
2. full restart
3. restarting the android studio
4. restarting the laptop
5. uninstalling the App from my device
6. and reinstalling the app as new

but still nothing

Comment: Try to change or reinstall the android emulator that you are using. Sometimes the same issues occurs to me, I usually solve the issue by reinstalling the android emulator.

Comment: reinstalling is not a permanent solution to every problem. Sometimes you have to debug every thing every line.